# 26 hour layover in Almaty, Kazakhstan

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, kazakhstan, almaty

I am an Indian citizen living in Ukraine. I will be traveling to India but I need to wait in Almaty airport 26 hours for my next flight to India. I will not be leaving Almaty airport. My flight is Air Astana. So in this case do I need a transit visa ?

Comment: You're going to spend the whole time in the airport?  I know Almaty is a bit drab, but even to get to the airport hotel you need to go landside

Comment: @GayotFow guess it's a question of which is more inconvenient, waiting for 26h or the hassle of getting a transit visa

Comment: @Blackbird57, I see.  In that case he should just go ahead and apply for one, and get a rejection (not refusal) if he doesn't need one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, official airline information from [TIMATIC](http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/) says that you need a visa.

```
Information as of  27JUN15 / 1842 UTC
National India (IN)             /Residence Ukraine (UA)
Embarkation Ukraine (UA)        /Transit Kazakhstan (KZ)
Destination India (IN)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW

Kazakhstan (KZ)


TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
time of 24 hours.
Additional Information:
- Holders of a transit visa must also hold documents required
for their next destination.
Warning:
- Holders of a transit visa are required to also hold onward
tickets.

Kazakhstan (KZ)

Vaccination against yellow fever required if arriving within 6
days after leaving or transiting countries with risk of yellow
.

Exempt from Yellow Fever vaccination:
- Children under 9 months of age.
- Passengers transiting Kazakhstan provided not leaving the
transit area.
- Passengers transiting countries with risk of yellow fever
transmission provided not leaving the transit areas.
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the quoted information?

Comment: @JoErNanO I have a feed from TIMATIC by a private subscription but a version of it is publicly available

Comment: @JoErNanO Direct links are no longer possible.  A lot of the existing Timatic links on this site will probably start breaking.

Comment: Link is no longer working.