# Transit Visa Almaty for Indian Citizens?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kazakhstan, ala

I am an Indian citizen. I will be travelling to Russia but I need to wait in Almaty airport 13 hours for my next flight to Russia. I will not be leaving Almaty airport. So in this case do I need a transit visa ?

Comment: Related: [26 hour layover in Almaty, Kazakhstan](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50184/26)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to transit without visa according to [Timatic](http://www.skyteam.com/en/Why-SkyTeam/Services/Visa-and-Health/):

> Summary
>
> No, The travel documents held are not sufficient for the traveler's journey, or they may need additional documents as follows:
>
> Type: Critical
>   Russian Federation - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold documents required for their next destination.
>
> Visitors are strongly recommended to hold a health/travel insurance to cover for any medical expenses.
>
> Important:
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.
>
> Type: Ok
>   Russian Federation - Destination Health
>
> This information is for guide purposes only. Other health organisations may recommend alternative precautions.
>
> Vaccinations not required.
>
> Type: Notice
>   Kazakhstan - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Transiting without a visa is possible for:
>
> Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> Type: Notice
>   Kazakhstan - Transit Health
>
> This information is for guide purposes only. Other health organisations may recommend alternative precautions.
>
> Vaccination against yellow fever required if arriving within 6 days after leaving or transiting countries with risk of yellow fever transmission .
>
> Exempt from Yellow Fever vaccination:
>
> Children under 9 months of age.
>
> Passengers transiting Kazakhstan provided not leaving the transit area.
>
> Passengers transiting countries with risk of yellow fever transmission provided not leaving the transit areas.